# Get DDL of Netezza UDF

Tags: netezza

We are working on Migrating netezza to Snowflake. And their are some functions in Netezza which needs to migrated as well.
However Like we can get the function defination in snowflake with below command.

```
Select get_ddl('Function','Get_beta(i int)');
```

Do we any thing similar in Netezza. We are using Dbeaver to connect to Netezza. and have no access to Netezza terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you migrating data without access to Netezza's tools?

Comment: The Data is already migrated now we are migrating Store proc, ETL etc. Store Proc we can see in DBeaver So got the DDL but function is not visible, And hence getting stuck.

Comment: Which functions are you referring to? ...functions you wrote originally or functions built-in to Netezza? If you wrote them originally why aren't they in your source-control system?

Comment: Are any of these UDFs/UDX objects compiled (e.g. using `nzudxcompile`)? If so then you'll be SOL as there won't be a source-form representation in Netezza.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM _v_function`? [It's listed here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=views-user) and [mentioned here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/391).

Comment: Yes I was looking for something similar, however I see it is in _v_aggregate and is not a function. And in _v_aggregate it does not have any defination, Seems like I will have to contact the DBA to get the DDL of this aggregate.. Thank you for your help